# Difference between parameterized and raw type instantiation in java

Tags: java, generics

Say, I have a class `Alpha` with two formal parameters `K and V`.

Now, I want to initialize an object of it with concrete types `CK and CV`.

I want to know, what's the difference between

```
Alpha<CK, CV> alpha = new Alpha<CK, CV>();
```

and,

```
Alpha<CK, CV> alpha = new Alpha();
```

Since, both won't allow me to write or read anything other than what they are declared as. And, since, generics is only for ensuring type safety during compile time, why does it throws warning if I can't do anything wrong with it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: And what prior research did you do? You know, like reading the excellent tutorials from Oracle on generics, that very well answer all your questions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with

```
Alpha<CK, CV> alpha = new Alpha();
```

is that on the left hand side, you are using the generic type Alpha where on the right side you are using the raw type Alpha. Raw types in Java effectively only exist for compatibility with pre-generics code and should never be used in new code unless you absolutely have to.

As far as your original example of `Alpha<CK, CV> alpha = new Alpha()`, the compiler generates a warning for that assignment because it must. Consider this:

```
List<String> strings = ... // some list that contains some strings

// Totally legal since you used the raw type and lost all type checking!
List<Integer> integers = new LinkedList(strings);
```

Generics exist to provide compile-time protection against doing the wrong thing. In the above example, using the raw type means you don't get this protection and will get an error at runtime. This is why you should not use raw types.

```
// Not legal since the right side is actually generic!
List<Integer> integers = new LinkedList<>(strings);
```

Comment: Yes. Know that :). What I want to know is, what bad can someone do by declaring it this way, which is not possible when declared and instantiated with parameterized types? Thanks.

Comment: @PkeakhJoqo i edited :)

Comment: Thanks :). So, is there any issue you can think of, if the constructor takes no parameter?